# SSRS 2008 R2 Charts cropped and blurry

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I hope anybody can help me with this. When I insert a chart into a new report (SSRS 2008 R2) in Visual Studio preview everything looks fine and sharp. But when I deploy and open the same report within the browser (IE 9 & Firefox) the chart is blurry and cut off on the right hand side as well as at the bottom. Finally, when I print the report everything is fine again.

I have included a screenshot
 [image: screenshot]  to better explain what I mean. Would be grateful for any hint on this problem!

Thanks a lot!

Andreas

Comment: I have the same problem with my reports in SharePoint 2010 reportviewer. They look fine in VS or ReportBuilder but cropped when viewed in SharePoint. Anyone with a solution to this would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Hi David,

I don´t have a 'real' solution yet - but: I installed my application at the customers real environment in the meanwhile and everything worked fine there. Cant say what the difference there is, but I guess it must have something to do with the environment or a bad installation of SQL Server on my development VM ... :-/

Comment: Yes, I agree, it doesn't seem to be a problem when you access the server from another machine. A bit strange but on the other hand, the purpose of sharepoint is to be used remote...

Comment: I have exactly the same issue on "local mode" SSRS reports - they look fine on my local deployment, but on production they are blurry!

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to image resolution.  [This website](http://blog.toddtaylor.com/PermaLink,guid,b1517702-ad4b-48e1-a6e3-b736e8a982cb.aspx) explains it:

> Most monitors have a resolution in the range of 72 to 96 dpi (so I’ve been told), where as an image should be at least 150 dpi (dots per inch) in order to print with any clarity. [...] Higher resolution images look very blurry and pixilated when displayed on-screen but should print very nicely.

Perhaps reporting services is rendering the image at a resolution suitable for printing, and then scaling/cropping it to make it fit on the screen?